# Changing font style in excel from vb6?

Tags: excel, vb6

i am currently coding a button to transfer all the data from a listview into an excel workbook so it can be printed as barcode labels. the way the barcode works is that it is a true type font. im running into the problem however through vb6 where i dont know how to format a range of cells to have a different font style so i can change certain cells to be able to show barcodes. ive gotten as far as

```
oSheet.range("D2:D10").Font
```

where D2:D10 is not the set range of cells just ones i was playing with. im not sure where to go after the font property here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
oSheet.range("D2:D10").Font.Name = "BarCode Font Name"
```

Comment: yes i tried that, it shows an error saying "Object doesnt support this property or method". that way makes sense though!

Comment: What about .Font.Name?

Comment: or .Style.Font.FontName